# In Swift, how do I make private variables visible to code in an extension which is in a separate file?

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I took some legacy code I did not write, splitting a large view controller pretty much evenly into two portions. The main one contains everything but the callbacks from the ui, and all the callbacks were moved into an extension. I did all this in one file, which made it easy to do.

However, when I created the second file and moved the extension code to it there was one messy detail. Once half the code was moved into a separate file, things  broke.  Methods in the extension couldn’t use the private properties defined in the main file. How do make a property available to only other elements of the same class, even if parts of the class are in another file? My workaround is to not have any private variables, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, UI callbacks, properties (outlets) and stuff like that is supossed to be managed by the view controller. You can create another file that actually handles the data and call it from the view controller. This is actually used by some code architectures like [VIPER](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/), at which you have an **interactor** (business logic) and a **presenter** (formats data and chooses when to present it). The view controller is passive. So it calls `didSelect...` on the interactor, it processes and it then calls `updateData...` on the presenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these two Swift Evolution proposals already implemented in Swift 4

[SE-0025 Scoped Access Level](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0025-scoped-access-level.md)

[SE-0169 Improve Interaction Between `private` Declarations and Extensions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0169-improve-interaction-between-private-declarations-and-extensions.md)

Since SE-0025 was accepted and implemented, an extension cannot access `private` members of the extended type.

SE-0169 loosened this rule a little, but the extension still needs to be in the same source file of the original type definition, to access `private` members.

***My workaround is to not have any private variables***

That's one practical solution for your issue, or else you may need to move all extensions accessing `private` members into the same source file.

Comment: In other words, not using `private` but having the default (`internal`) access level would solve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding the code from the two separate files back into the same file. There's nothing wrong with having the main declaration of a type, along with any extensions of that type, in the same file. This allows you to use `fileprivate` for anything that you want to be private, such as variables, but anything that is in the same file can access them.

**Update**

As OOPer mentions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51228835/in-swift-how-do-i-make-private-variables-visible-to-code-in-an-extension-which/51228937#answer-51228922) answer, `fileprivate` can be replaced with `private` as of [SE-0169](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0169-improve-interaction-between-private-declarations-and-extensions.md).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I do appreciate it (upvoted). Right now I have two 400+ line files, and I don't want to go back to an 800 line file. I was using private, but will drop it for now. Once my entire project (150+ classes) is stable I will take a fresh look at refactoring these two files into more than one class.